# Updating Values in Dictionary with for Loop of a List within a List

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, python-itertools

I know the logic/syntax of the code at the bottom of this post is off, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how I can write this to get the desired result. The first section creates this dictionary:

```
sco = {'human + big': 0, 'big + loud': 0, 'big + human': 0, 'human + loud': 0, 'loud + big': 0, 'loud + human': 0}
```

Then, my intention is to loop through each item in the dictionary "cnt" once for x and then loop through the dictionary a second time for x each time the item has the same value as (cnt[x][1]) but a different key (cnt[x][0]), creating a string that will match the format "%s + %s" found in the dictionary "sco." It should then find the key in sco that matches the key assigned to the variable dnt and increment the value for that key in sco by 1.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import itertools
sho = ('human', 'loud', 'big')
sco = {}
for a,b in itertools.permutations(sho, 2):
    sco["{0} + {1}".format(a,b)] = 0

cnt = [('human', 'ron g.'), ('loud', 'ron g.'), ('big', 'kim p.'), ('human', 'kim p.'), ('loud', 'brian a.'), ('human', 'linda m.'), ('loud', 'linda m.')]
for x in cnt:
    upd = cnt[x][0]
    who = cnt[x][1]
    for x in cnt:
        if cnt[x][0] != upd and cnt[x][1] == who:
            cpg = cnt[x][0]
            dnt = '%s + %s' % (upd, cpg)
            for i in sco:
                if sco[i][0] == dnt:
                    sco[i][1] += sco[i][1]
print sco
```

Currently, printing sco results in no change to any of the values. The desired outcome of the code is this:

```
{'human + big': 1, 'big + loud': 0, 'big + human': 1, 'human + loud': 2, 'loud + big': 0, 'loud + human': 2}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

The revised code is this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import itertools
sho = ('human', 'loud', 'big')
sco = {}
for a,b in itertools.permutations(sho, 2):
    sco["{0} + {1}".format(a,b)] = 0

cnt = [('human', 'ron g.'), ('loud', 'ron g.'), ('big', 'kim p.'), ('human', 'kim p.'), ('loud', 'brian a.'), ('human', 'linda m.'), ('loud', 'linda m.')]
for x in cnt:
    upd = cnt[0]
    who = cnt[1]
    for x in cnt:
        if cnt[0] != upd and cnt[1] == who:
            cpg = cnt[0]
            dnt = '%s + %s' % (upd, cpg)
            sco[dnt] += 1
print sco
```

The following code does what I intended. Thank you to @dermen & @abarnert:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import itertools
sho = ('human', 'loud', 'big')
sco = {}
for a,b in itertools.permutations(sho, 2):
    sco["{0} + {1}".format(a,b)] = 0

cnt = [('human', 'ron g.'), ('loud', 'ron g.'), ('big', 'kim p.'), ('human', 'kim p.'), ('loud', 'brian a.'), ('human', 'linda m.'), ('loud', 'linda m.')]
for x in cnt:
    upd = x[0]
    who = x[1]
    for x in cnt:
        if x[0] != upd and x[1] == who:
            cpg = x[0]
            dnt = '%s + %s' % (upd, cpg)
            sco[dnt] += 1
print sco
```

Comment: i'm wondering, how your dictionary `cnt` could have same keys, **keys need to be unic**. It's a first problem in your script

Comment: I see. I'll update my post so that cnt is instead a list within a list. I think this creates a different problem though, right? Since list indices need to be integers.

Comment: I think you are misunderstand how to reference a dictionary...

Comment: dermen, how do you mean?

Comment: @dermen You were right -- I was referencing cnt[] when I should have been referencing x[]. Major kudos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is that, instead of adding 1 to the values, you're doubling them:

```
sco[i][1] += sco[i][1]
```

And no matter how many times you add 0 to 0, it's still 0.

To add 1, just use `+= 1`.

---

But you've got another problem, at least in the code you posted. Each `sco[i]` value just a number, not a list of two things, the second of which is a number. So what you really want is:

```
sco[i] += 1
```

And similarly, the keys aren't `sco[i][0]`, they're just `i`.

---

And you've got a third problem. This one doesn't actually *break* your code, it just makes it more complicated, harder to understand, and slower… but that's still worth fixing.

The whole point of dictionaries is that you don't have to iterate them to search for a key, you just look up the key directly. So, instead of this:

```
for i in sco:
    if i == dnt:
        sco[i] += 1
```

… just do this:

```
sco[dnt] += 1
```

It's simpler, harder to get wrong, and more efficient, all at the same time.

---

I can't promise there are no other errors in your code, but you definitely need to fix these three, on top of whatever else is wrong, and I'm pretty sure the first one is the one that happens to be causing the specific problem you asked about.

Comment: abarnert, I really appreciate your help. Rather than running and printing an unaltered version of sco, the code runs and spits back an error. If I leave cnt as a list, it says that list indices must be integers, but if I revert cnt to a dictionary as I had it originally, it says KeyError: 'k + 1'. I'm very new to Python -- going to look these errors up now and see what I can do. Again, really appreciate the help!!

Comment: @Will: I'm not sure why you're changing `cnt` when the error is with `sco`. And I can't imagine how you could get `KeyError: 'k + 1'` from anything in your original code or anything in my answer, so I have no idea what you're actually running.

Comment: I misspoke -- I made the change to the code that applies to sco in the second loop. I'm going to update my original post with the code that I'm running now. It's currently printing 0 for all the values. I really can't thank you enough for taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @abarnert replied, Dictionaries behave like this:

```
>>> D1 = { 'thing1': [1,2,3  ], 'thing2': ( 1, 2,3), 'thing3':'123'  }
>>> D1['thing1']
#[1, 2, 3]

>>> D1['thing2']
#(1, 2, 3)

>>> D1['thing3']
#'123'

>>> thing4 = 1
>>> D2 = { thing4:D1 } 
>>> D2[thing4]
#{'thing1': [1, 2, 3], 'thing2': (1, 2, 3), 'thing3': '123'}
```

If you want to iterate over the keys of a dictionary, use

```
>>> D1.keys()
#['thing2', 'thing3', 'thing1']
>>> D2.keys()
#[1]
```

Finally, I would suggest making a template for your "key", such that

```
>>> template = "{0} + {1}"
```

Then you can replace the line

```
sco["{0} + {1}".format(a,b)] = 0
```

with

```
sco[template.format(a,b)] = 0
```

and similarly

```
dnt = '%s + %s' % (upd, cpg)
```

with

```
dnt = template.format(upd, cpg)
```

-that is safer practice in my opinion. Read more on dictionaries [here, see section 5.5.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: How is this "in addition to"? It's pretty much the same thing as the "a third problem" part of my answer, except for the whole bit about iterating over the keys of a dictionary—which he was already doing correctly (`for key in d:`) and you're just giving him a more complicated (and slower, in 2.x) way to do.

Comment: You answered as I was finishing this post. Besides, I think it is very relevant for someone who is "very new to Python" to see the different ways that Dictionaries can work

Comment: so instead of answer, you both trying to be a teacher? :)  P.S.  `'%s + %s' % (upd, cpg)` is nice short form and could be used, while u don't need something like "{0} ...{1}...{0}" or extended formating

Comment: Also, he was iterating over the keys, sure, but based on the way he structured the code, I assume he thought he was iterating over a dictionary key:value element (hence the reason he coded ```sco[i][0]``` etc). This is why I clarified, something I think you did not elaborate on, you just stated.

Comment: @Reishin, its just that I love dictionaries and im trying to share that love!

Answer (score 0):

Solution with using defaultdict and grouping by item in tuple:

```
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

sho = ('human', 'loud', 'big')
sco = {}
for a, b in itertools.permutations(sho, 2):
  sco["{0} + {1}".format(a, b)] = 0

cnt = [('human', 'ron g.'), ('loud', 'ron g.'), ('big', 'kim p.'), ('human', 'kim p.'), ('loud', 'brian a.'), ('human', 'linda m.'), ('loud', 'linda m.')]

groups = defaultdict(list)

for obj in cnt:
  groups[obj[1]].append(obj[0])

final_list = []

# create list of pairs a + b
final_list.extend(map(lambda x: " + ".join(x), groups.values()))

for key in groups.keys():
  groups[key].reverse()

# create list of pairs b + a
final_list.extend(map(lambda x: " + ".join(x), groups.values()))

for val in final_list:
  if val in sco:
    sco[val] += 1

print(sco)
```

Here we:

- grouping `cnt` tuple by person in to a dict
- create list of value pairs from previous step
- create reverse pairs(according to expected results of OP)
- count existed pairs in `sco`

Result:

```
 {'human + loud': 2, 'loud + human': 2, 'loud + big': 0, 'human + big': 1, 'big + loud': 0, 'big + human': 1}
```